# control reload of 3rd party javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser-cache, mobile-website

We are developing a third party java script file that is implemented as a widget on many sites (That we **do not** control the code of).

This script may be updated from time to time (As we modify it/ add abilities/ fix bug ...)

As the browser saves most js files in cache, we need to have some sort of solution to tell the browser to reload the Script. of course a naive solution is to make re-load always, but this solution is not very efficient, and code changes should not accrue often.

Any idea how this can be done?
The solution of changing our script src/url with "?version=1.1.1" cannot be applied here as this widget is third party and we do not have any control on clients website codes.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought of manual DOM manipulation as in document.write?

Comment: He would have to completely reload the js then after it wrote the version string to the document which would be a performance hit by loading the whole script 2 times.

Comment: I thought about - always loading script A- which is very small size, and inside it load the main script with current version, and then the browser always load script A, and only load my main script if version is different, What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are the 3rd party and are giving your clients a link to the javascript file they need to include, have them point at your javascript with a url like this:

```
http://example.com/file.js
```

Then use a redirect on your server (Url Rewrite/htaccess etc) to point them to the latest version of that file.  Lets say you versioned your script by putting it into a folder and your latest version was 1.3.  You would setup the redirect from http://example.com/file.js to http://example.com/1.3/file.js.  Then every time you release a new version, update your redirect to point to the new folder.

EDIT: More detailed explanation

Comment: I am sorry, I do not underhand your respond, nor the example.